# Can I restrict a CQ5 template for specific user group

Tags: aem

I need to restrict the template to be available only for a set of user.  The template should not be available for other users while creating new page.  How can I do that in CQ5?

Answer (score 2):

First, read this [documentation page](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/security.html). After that create an group containing all users which should be able to create a page using the template. Then add following ACLs to the template node (eg. `/apps/myapp/templates/mytemplate`):

```
deny    jcr:all    for everyone
allow   jcr:read   for (created group)
```

Comment: Has anyone tried this in the wild? Are there any less-than-ideal side-effects? For instance: how does the siteadmin interface handle this for restricted users looking to add new pages from otherwise allowed templates?